# How to add Azure Portal to myapps.microsoft.com

Tags: azure, office365

I have users able to access portal.azure.com with restricted permissions (RBAC model) for assurance tasks.

I would like to add an Azure Portal tile to myapps.microsoft.com and Office365 for that group of users.

I am unable to find guidance on how to integrate the Azure Portal

Answer (score 0):

In order to add the Azure Portal and the Office 365 management portal, try adding an application with "existing SSO solution".  This will allow you to simply add a link to an application and place it on the access panel.

See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-access-panel-introduction/#launching-applications for more information.

Users will sign into the access panel, click on the azure portal link, and be taken right there.  They would have already authenticated with AAD, so no further authentication would need to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Portal with RBAC controls can be added to myapps.microsoft.com by adding it as an "Application with Existing SSO solutions" mentioned in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-saas-access-panel-introduction/#launching-applications

This is achieved in the AD Classic portal by adding an application to the directory and following the workflow for "Add an application my organisation is developing"

It does not seem possible for portal.azure.com to be a microsoft application that can be federated against it's own AD.